# How to Customise Social Account model in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to add some additional field to SocialAccount model in allauth.socialaccount.models
Not able to find anything in the official documentation.

What I am trying to do is Save all the data received in extra_data to individual fields like.

```
facebook_id = models.TextField(default='')
first_name = models.TextField(default='')
middle_name = models.TextField(default='')
last_name = models.TextField(default='')
email = models.TextField(default='')
short_name = models.TextField(default='')
hometown = models.TextField(default='')
location = models.TextField(default='')
```

Or If i can tell Django-allauth to save data of SocialAccount model to some other model.

Alternatively, If i can redirect the user to a different URL after successful facebook login and can save the data into my own models.

That way I will just be using social auth for Login

Comment: Why do you want to customise `SocialAccount` and not just your `User` model? Maybe it would help if tell us what you're trying to do and there might be a different solution than to customise `SocialAccount`. Reason I'm saying is that I don't think it would be easy to use you're own `SocialAccount` subclass.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have updated my question

Comment: I don't think these fields should be added to `SocialAccount`, you should add them to a `UserProfile` or your `User` itself. In order to have them saved, you can subclass the `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter` and override the `populate_user()` method.

Comment: @dirkgroten is it possible to redirect the user to a different URL after successful facebook login and can save the data into my own models?

Comment: Yes, you can: create your own `SignupForm` (subclass allauth's) and declare it in your _settings.py_ as `SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'myapp.SignupForm'}`. And set `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP` to `False`.